# I replaced the plug in the garage and arced. Now I some plug work and some do not?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I changed a plug in the garage that the door opener is plugged into. While i arced the wires and now the light in the garage does not work, the attic does not work. The lights and fans in the master bedroom and the light in the utility room light are out as well.  Checked the breaker and the breaker seems fine and is actually good because the garage door still works. I am not sure what to do .  I changed out the breaker anyway and still nothing. I changed the light switches in the garage, utility room, and master bedroom?

Comment: It's possible there is a GFCI outlet in the chain here somewhere.  Often they are hidden away in the garage somewhere.  If you search around you might find it and reset it.

Comment: You have learned a lesson to kill the power in the box when doing work. It is possible you have Old multiwire branch circuit without handle ties, so a different breaker or possibly a GFCI may have tripped on another circuit since the receptacle you were working on is functional. If you reset your breakers (turn off and on) and no GFCI is found work back to the panel looking for the first working receptacle or switch if a failed connection is the cause as common with backstabs it will be in the last working device or first non working device in the chain.

Comment: "in the garage" - in EMT with metal boxes? A mistake I used to make was not making absolutely sure none of the **wires were caught between the surface mount cover plate and the box (?)**. If you do that, it goes *pop*, and until you take it back off and inspect the wires, you won't know wtf is going on. If there's one thing I'm sure of, it's that last part.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment as I am too new to the forum. When you say you arced the wires do you mean you caused them to arc flash? If this did happen your breaker should have tripped. Also are these lights on the same circuit? Were these lights switched on when this arc occurred? Was this arc between a live and earth wire?

I would try switching all the breakers off and back on as I've known breakers to stick, where they look like they are on but they have actually tripped. I would also suggest checking the bulbs of these lights, if they were on at the time you could have burnt the filaments out or blown the leds dependent on the type of bulbs because an arc causes a surge of current which can cause bulbs the 'pop'. This definitely should have caused the breaker to trip otherwise the breaker is not fit for purpose and should be assessed by an electrician.